# Form class fails to render HTML markup - Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('register', function(){
return View::make('register');
});
```

with my register view as so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Register!</h2>
  {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register')) }}
  {{ Form::close() }}
 </body>
</html>
```

However the stuff between the braces fails to generate any HTML at all? All I see is:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

in the browser when really

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/register" accept-charset="UTF-8">
 <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="1gDaHZGie4TwE47wIT7T7uUU5hQOKu8hfFHG6Dwj">
</form>
```

should be displayed? Have you seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.blade.php` to your view file name

You probably have your file named `view.php`

You need to name your file `view.blade.php`

Comment: Works with .blade included. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My problem here was that I had used double-curly brackets: `{{ some code here }}` instead of using a curly followed by two exclamation marks: `{!! some code here !!}`. Laravel 5.1 on PHP 5.5.